# Adjusting a pre-made URL shortening script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not familiar with javascript and I'm sure the problem I have has a simple solution, I just need some direction.

The script below wasn't written by me, it's an URL shortening script. When the user inputs the long URL and presses submit the script creates a random short URL and displays the short URL in the input field. What I want to know is which part of the javascript controls the display of the short URL in the input? I want to change what is displayed after the URL is shortened.

page.php

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form action="#" id="form-add-url" class="profile" method="post" onsubmit="return add_url()">
    <input type="text" id="urls-url" name="url" class="widefat-main" placeholder="Paste a link" tabindex="1" title="URL">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_url">
    <button type="submit" class="button-main" tabindex="3">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

script.js

```
function add_url() {
    jQuery("#front-url .loading-dark").fadeIn(200);
    jQuery.post(url_base+"ajax.php", jQuery("#form-add-url").serialize(),
        function(return_data) {
            jQuery("#front-url .loading-dark").fadeOut(200);
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(return_data);
            var status = data.status;
            if (status == "OK") {
                jQuery("#urls-url").val(data.url);
            } else if (status == "OK2") {
                jQuery("#search_query").val("");
                jQuery("#page_number").val("");
                reload_urls("", 1);
                jQuery("#urls-url").val(data.url);
            } else if (status == "ERROR") {
                show_notification("error", data.message, 3000);
            } else {
                show_notification("error", "Internal error. Please contact administrator.", 3000);
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

My PHP:

```
case 'add_url':
    if ($options['only_registered'] == 'yes' && !$active_user)
        {
        $return_object = new stdClass();
        $return_object->message = 'URL shortening is available for registerd users only.';
        $return_object->status = 'ERROR';
        echo json_encode($return_object);
        exit;
        }

    $url = trim(stripslashes($_POST['url']));
    if (substr(strtolower($url) , 0, 7) != "http://" && substr(strtolower($url) , 0, 8) != "https://") $url = 'http://' . $url;
    $error = '';
    if ($url == '')
        {
        $error = 'Hey, seems you forgot to paste a link.';
        }
      else
    if (!preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url))
        {
        $error = 'Are you sure you submitted the correct URL?';
        }
      else
    if (sizeof($url) > 255)
        {
        $error = 'Hey, seems URL is too long.';
        }

    if (!empty($error))
        {
        $return_object = new stdClass();
        $return_object->message = $error;
        $return_object->status = 'ERROR';
        echo json_encode($return_object);
        exit;
        }

    if (substr(strtolower($url) , 0, strlen($url_base)) == strtolower($url_base))
        {
        $return_object = new stdClass();
        $return_object->message = 'Hey. Seems this URL is short enough. ;-)';
        $return_object->status = 'ERROR';
        echo json_encode($return_object);
        exit;
        }

    if ($active_user) $user_id = $active_user['id'];
      else $user_id = 0;
    $url_details = $icdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM " . $icdb->prefix . "urls WHERE url = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($url) . "' AND deleted = '0' AND user_id = '" . $user_id . "'");
    if ($url_details)
        {
        $icdb->query("UPDATE " . $icdb->prefix . "urls SET created = '" . time() . "' WHERE id = '" . $url_details['id'] . "'");
        $url_code = $url_details['url_code'];
        }
      else
        {
        $icdb->query("INSERT INTO " . $icdb->prefix . "urls (user_id, url, url_code, redirects, created, blocked, deleted, short) VALUES ('" . $user_id . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($url) . "', '', '0', '" . time() . "', '0', '0', '" . $_POST[short] . "')");
        $url_code = url_code($icdb->insert_id);
        $icdb->query("UPDATE " . $icdb->prefix . "urls SET url_code = '" . $url_code . "' WHERE id = '" . $icdb->insert_id . "'");
        }

    $htaccess = url_rewrite();
    $return_object = new stdClass();
    if ($active_user)
        {
        $return_object->status = 'OK2';
        }
      else $return_object->status = 'OK';
    $return_object->url = $url_base . ($htaccess ? '' : '?u=') . $url_code;
    echo json_encode($return_object);
    exit;
    break;
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. Also, **please update your question title to be meaningful**

Comment: @ThiefMaster - note that it's not a DOM ready handler, that would be `jQuery(function($) { .... });`

Comment: I think the part of the code you are looking for is on the server side, being returned by ajax... DO you have the PHP code?

Comment: @adeneo: Correct. I do not believe combining those two is a good idea. My comment was only to get rid of the ugly `jQuery()` calls. ;)

Comment: @Sergio
See http://111.118.164.146/~jodeleep/ajax.php.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out

```
    function add_url() {
        // fading effect
        jQuery("#front-url .loading-dark").fadeIn(200);
        // posting with ajax post method
        jQuery.post(url_base+"ajax.php", jQuery("#form-add-url").serialize(),
            // success function after request complete
            function(return_data) {
                // applying fade out effect
                jQuery("#front-url .loading-dark").fadeOut(200);

                //parsing response string from server into javascript object
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(return_data);
                // getting status value
                var status = data.status;
                if (status == "OK") {
                    //putting [data.url] value in html element with id [urls-url]
                    //data.url => url value from server
                    jQuery("#urls-url").val(data.url);
                } else if (status == "OK2") {
                    jQuery("#search_query").val("");
                    jQuery("#page_number").val("");
                    reload_urls("", 1);
                    jQuery("#urls-url").val(data.url);
                } else if (status == "ERROR") {
                    show_notification("error", data.message, 3000);
                } else {
                    show_notification("error", "Internal error. Please contact administrator.", 3000);
                }
            }
        );
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#urls-url").val(data.url);
```

In the response of the post to url_base+"ajax.php" a JSON string is returned. The URL part of this response (data.url) is used as a value for you input (#urls-url).

Comment: So the data would be returned from ajax.php? (http://111.118.164.146/~jodeleep/ajax.php.html)

Comment: url_base+'ajax.php'; I'm not sure what the value is of url_base, but you can find out using your console and check your XHR requests.

Comment: url_base is the domain the script is installed on. I have modified the script slightly so that the short url domain is not the same as the one the script is installed on

Comment: Would this line be the one I should change url_base - $return_object->url = $url_base.($htaccess ? '' : '?u=').$url_code;

Comment: Could you share the PHP also?

Comment: @meavo, just posted it in the question.

Comment: I don't see the complete PHP, but it looks like you need to just modify the value of $url_base somewhere outside you're PHP snippet. Otherwise you could indeed change the line you mention; but I kinda like the variable :)

Comment: Sorted it, the line I need to change is:
$return_object->url = $url_base.($htaccess ? '' : '?u=').$url_code;

Comment: @meavo its the 4th last line

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
jQuery("#urls-url").val(data.url);
```

The .val() method is used to get and set the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys! Very much appreciated.
The 4th last line in ajax.php (111.118.164.146/~jodeleep/ajax.php.html) was what I need to look for.